# SSH Renegotiation is not working properly

Tags: unix, ssh, daemon

Changing of SSH deamon side ciphers is not affecting ongoing session,While performing SSH renegotiation for protocol SSHv2 using rekeyLimit tag in sshd_config file.

We have modified /etc/ssh/sshd_config file with rekeyLimit as below :

reKeyLimit default 30s

So,for every 30seconds renegotiation is performed for ongoing sessions.But when we change cipher values in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file which are incompatible to client ciphers,New sessions are not getting opened but the existing sessions are ongoing.

Is there any cache present in SSH that needs to be cleanedup to consider new ciphers for ongoing sessions ?? Or Do we need to set any options in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file for the chaneges to be considered for ongoing sessions??

Comment: How can we do negative testing to check SSH renegotiation in SSHv2 protocol?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. The server is reading the configuration only once when it starts. It is very good practice to be fail proof against people editing the configuration files and introducing errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But how do we make sure that renegotiation is happening for ongoing SSH session.Especially how can we do negative testing to check SSH renegotiation in SSHv2 protocol?

Comment: You will see it in the logs if you turn on verbose or debug log level.

Comment: In detail i would like to explain my testing scenario.

I opened a SSH session after that i changed ciphers in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
Now i want to know how new keys are generated with new ciphers,KEX,MACS and how these are reflected in existing session during renegotiation
The main intention of our testing is to drop existing SSH session during renegotiation.
Is there any way to achieve this in SSH.